# How do I provide single instance of service for component and all content children?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

Is there a way I can provide my component-scoped service to all of its content children?

For context, I am building out a table component that contains multiple components and directives that are injected via `<ng-content>`.

I am providing the service to the component like this:

```
@Component({
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class Table {
  ...

  constructor(private _service: MyService) {}
}
```

If I have another component, say:

```
@Component({

})
export class HeaderCell {
  ...

  constructor(private _service: MyService) {}
}
```

How can I design this in a way that the `HeaderCell` component receives the same instance of  `MyService` that is used by the top level `Table` component?

Do I have to pass the instance via `@Input()` to the `ContentChildren`?

What are my options?

Comment: Some keywords: @Host and viewProviders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy. Here is our

**HTML**

```
<div>START</div>
<hr />
<app-parent><app-child></app-child></app-parent>
<hr />
```

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
  providers: [TestService]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private test: TestService) { }
  testValue: string = ""
  ngOnInit() {
    this.test.message = "From Parent";
    this.testValue = this.test.message;
  }
}

// HTML
<div>{{testValue}}</div>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

**The Child Component**

```
import { Component, Host, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TestService } from '../../test.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  //providers: [TestService]
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  //constructor(@Host() private test: TestService) { }
  constructor(private test: TestService) { }
  testValue: string = '';
  ngOnInit() {
    //this.test.message = "From Child"
    this.testValue = this.test.message
  }
}

// HTML
<div>CHILD {{testValue}}</div>
```

The **Service** is very small:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  message: string = "Init"
}
```

The `@Host()` helps to get the Service (or anything) from the parent directly. But is it a `Service` you don't need it. Is the service `provided` in the Parent then the Child have access to it, too - with the **same** instance! We set in the Parent the message value to **From Parent** and so looks the result:

[image]

You see the child show *From Parent*, too. Come from the same service instance.

Comment: Ahh so it looks like what I was looking for is more or less the default behavior. I probably should have done some more research before posting the question. Thank you!